# How to prove $\sum^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$ non-Abelian?

Tags: symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product, direct-product, wreath-product

How do I prove that $\sum^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$ is a non-Abelian group?

Here, $i, N_i, m_i$ are positive integers, $S_{N_i}$ is the symmetric group over $N_i$ symbols, $D_{m_i}$ is the dihedral group of order $2 m_i$.

Comment: Because any of the factors is a subgroup, and none of those are abelian unless all your indices are really small.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft did you mean $ S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$ by 'factor'?

Comment: Yes (see my comment on your other question for why I didn't call it a summand).